# Dropbox android API bandwidth throttling, per connection? or per account? or both?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I noticed that dropbox perform bandwidth throttling
And by my guessing, I think it is PER-CONNECTION based, please correct me if wrong

For example, I am testing the dropbox android API
When I upload a single file, the peak upload speed is about 900 KBytes/s
But when I upload multiple files together, it peak at 2.5 MBytes/s

But I guessing that there is ALSO PER-ACCOUNT based throttling
because I tried upload more than 5 files in parallel but the peak is still around 2.5-3MBytes/s (should be >4MBytes/s if there is no PER-ACCOUNT throttling, but maybe it has reached the phone maximum upload bandwidth due to the phone 802.11n single channel)

Can anyone provide more accurate information about this issue?
Thank you

Also, can I use MULTIPLE chunked_upload (dropbox api new feature) to upload a single file?
So that I can bypass the per connection throttle.

Comment: still looking for help

Comment: An old thread but dropbox certainly appears to be throttling uploads.

Answer (score 1):

it's been a while but I doubt that Dropbox would throttle *upload* of files; generally uploading costs the provider very little, considering that a majority of bandwidth used by a company like Dropbox is from Dropbox Servers -> Users, not the other way around.

However, your results seem to show that they definitely do, at least for an individual connection. Very interesting. This may sound like a silly question, but what's your upload speed? 4MB/s is an extremely fast upload, so it wouldn't surprise me if the bottleneck was on your end. Let me know if you find anything! It's a cool question, sorry you didn't get any answers.

Comment: I was in South Korea, 100Mbps (roughly 10MBytes/ps) is very common in every home.

Maybe the 4MBps is limited by my phone 802.11n single channel and my router. But that is not the main question thou.

The main question is about whether they perform throttling.
Is it per account or per connection based?